# Asserting a Prop Contains a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme, fixed-data-table

I'm working with FixedDataTable (https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/) and I simply want to assert that the column headers are set correctly. Here is my component definition:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Table, Column, Cell} from 'fixed-data-table';

// Table data as a list of array.
const rows = [
  ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'],
  ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'],
  ['a3', 'b3', 'c3'],
  // .... and more
];

// Render your table

class TestTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Table
        rowHeight={50}
        rowsCount={rows.length}
        width={900}
        height={1000}
        headerHeight={50}>
        <Column
          header={<Cell>Column 1</Cell>}
          cell={<Cell>Column 1 static content</Cell>}
          width={300}
        />
        <Column
          header={<Cell>Column 2</Cell>}
          cell={<Cell>Column 2 static content</Cell>}
          width={300}
        />
        <Column
        header={<Cell>Column 3</Cell>}
        cell={({rowIndex, ...props}) => (
          <Cell {...props}>
          Data for column 3: {rows[rowIndex][2]}
          </Cell>
        )}
        width={300}
        />
      </Table>
    );
  }
}
```

My test is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import {Table, Column, Cell} from 'fixed-data-table';

import TestTable from '../../src/components/test_table';

describe('<TestTable/>', () => {

    it('renders a blank table', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<TestTable/>);
        //debugger;
        expect(wrapper.find(Table)).to.have.length(1);

        expect(wrapper.find(Table).children()).to.have.length(3);

        expect(wrapper.find(Table).childAt(0).prop('header')).to.equal(<Cell>Column 1</Cell>);
});
```

The test fails with the error:

> ‣ AssertionError: expected { Object ($$typeof, type, ...) } to equal {
>   Object ($$typeof, type, ...) }
>       at Context. (base/test/components/test_table_test.jsx:82:83)

How do I test that the headers are set to the values that I want it to be? How do I create a matcher that tests against a proc?

I'm using enzyme, react, mocha, and chai.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the Enzyme .is selector for checking that the component is a Cell and then check that it received a children prop of Column 1:

```
expect(wrapper.find(Table).childAt(0).prop('header').is(Cell)).to.be.true;
expect(wrapper.find(Table).childAt(0).prop('header').childAt(0)).to.equal('Column 1');
```

Documentation for .is: http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/is.html

Comment: no go. ```prop('header')``` is not an enzyme ShallowWrap'd component. It is a full blown component because enzyme seems to just follow the nodes and does not check the props if it should be shallow wrap'd or not. I get an error that "is" is not a function.

Comment: Could you try finding the header Cell using a css selector and check that it's parent is wrapper.find(Table).childAt(0)? Otherwise I don't know sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
expect(wrapper.find(Table).childAt(0).prop('header')).to.equal(<Cell>Column 1</Cell>);
```

does not work because it compares object identity and you are comparing to a different object. Try to use a deep equals comparison instead:

```
expect(wrapper.find(Table).childAt(0).prop('header')).to.deep.equal(<Cell>Column 1</Cell>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `prop()` returns ordinary object we can wrap that with `shallow()` or `mount()` to get Wrapper:

```
expect(
  shallow(wrapper.find(Table).childAt(0).prop('header')).find(Cell).prop("children")
).to.equal("Column 1");
```

or use any other matchers as you do against Wrappers